# Задача на множества Python

Tags: python, множества

Даны два числа. Верно ли утверждение, что для записи этих двух чисел использовались различные цифры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, задачу нужно решить именно через множества. В таком случае, переведём оба числа в множества из цифр (перед этим переведя числа в строки), и посмотрим, совпадают ли они.

```
if set(str(a)) == set(str(b)):
    # Да, оба числа составлены из разных цифр.
else:
    # Нет, оба числа составлены из одинаковых цифр.
```

(**a** и **b** это первое и второе число)